# JSON values in javascript get different outcome when used in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I been puzzled for a bit now with my javascript, which does a relatively simple task; gets JSON values as data-attributes to populate the modal. I am pretty new to this stuff!
Code works on the paragraph part, but not for the header.

My aim is to loop through the JSON, and pair up the values from header and paragraph into data-attributes. These I could then use to show the values in a modal.

Structure of my JSON:

```
var tableEntries = [
      {
          category : "learning",
          start : 8,
          end : 9,
          duration: 1,
          header : "Title of the modal", 
          paragraph : "Content of modal"
      },{
          category : "learning",
          start : 10,
          end : 11,
          duration: 1,
          header : "Title of the modal 2", 
          paragraph : "Content of modal 2"
      }];
```

Now I have a simple function that works to get the header:

```
function getHeader(header) {
      return '<h5 class="modalheader">'+ header + '</h5>';
  };
```

But after I try and use the JSON value from header in another function I cannot get it, it returns undefined

```
function createLinkforModal(paragraph, header) {

      return '<div class="readmore"><a href="#modal" data-target="#paragraph" class="openModal" id="openModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" '+paragraph+' " data-header="'+header+'">Read more &raquo;</a></div>'; }
```

I can get all values in this function BUT the header, and I cannot pinpoint what is different between header and paragraph in the JSON?

I can get a single header just by console logging, only now it prints it 2 times, since I have 2 values(loop is working as it should)

```
console.log(tableEntries[1].header);
```

When I log the paragraph it works as expected. But when I log the header right underneath this one, it is undefined.

```
console.log(paragraph);
console.log(header);
```

Here is also how I am doing the modal with bootstrap, with data-attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#paragraph").on("show.bs.modal", function(evt) {
        var $btn = $(evt.relatedTarget);
        var $modal = $(evt.target);
        var $header = $modal.find(".modal-header");
        var $content = $modal.find(".modal-body");

        $header.text($btn.data("header") );
        $content.text( $btn.data("id") );
    });
});
```

Also just looping the headers inside the function works, but I will get multiple loops, as it is a nested loop then. I am not sure I need to loop them like this if the paragraph already works as it should?

```
for(var i = 0;i < tableEntries.length;i++){
        (function(){
            var ii = i;
            //console.log(tableEntries[ii].header);
        })();
      }
```

I have been looking into JSON.parse() as well, but to no avail. And again, since I apparently do not need to do this for the paragraph, why should I need to for the headers? 
//EDIT 1

```
console.log(JSON.parse(header));
```

This gets me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

EDIT//2

I can use this to put all the headers into an Array outside the function:

```
var headers = [];

        $.each(tableEntries, function(index, value) {
            if ($.inArray(value.header, headers )==-1) {
                headers.push(value.header);
            }
        });
```

But then how would I loop through these inside my function, and keep the header and paragraph intact, as in the right pairing? Also I still do not understand why the paragraph works as it does, but I would need to do this to just the headers?

Comment: can you provide the function call where you get an unexpected result?

Comment: Are you calling the function like this : `createLinkforModal(tableEntries[1].paragraph, tableEntries[1].header);`

Comment: @Roman Edited the post to include the console.log(); where i get unexpected token.

Comment: @Shiladitya This gets me a syntax error. Also would this not only get me the second entry?

Comment: @StuffToLearn .. f`unction createLinkforModal(paragraph, header) {` here you are expecting two parameters, right??

Comment: @Shiladitya Yes, and from what I can see the paragraph works, and the header does not?

Comment: JSON in JavaScript is a string that contains stringified data. Your  `tableEntries` holds an JavaScript Object  in this case an array and **not** JSON. `JSON.parse(header)` would only work if `header`  contains stringified JSON data, but this is not the case.

Comment: @t.niese Yes that is what I figured but since it was an accepted answer in a lot of previous questions about undefined I had to give it a whirl :)

Comment: what is your goal for this question? you want to loop trough `tableEntries` to create with your to functions new `DOMElements`?

Comment: @Roman Basically, yes! I want to loop the JSON to get the values into data-attributes, then use the later bit of code to get the values to show up in my modal. For the paragraph part this is working so far, but the header only prints undefined into my modal.

Comment: What's resulting when console.log(header); called?

Comment: @StuffToLearn but you still call your `tableEntries` JSON through out the whole question. It is not JSON what you have there. You do not want to loop over JSON, you want to loop over an Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

TableEntries is an `array` and you can basicly loop trough it to get all `objects` in it.

### Solution

Your `functions` work correct. I didn't modified them.

```js
var tableEntries = [
  {
    category : "learning",
    start : 8,
    end : 9,
    duration: 1,
    header : "Title of the modal", 
    paragraph : "Content of modal"
  },
  {
    category : "learning",
    start : 10,
    end : 11,
    duration: 1,
    header : "Title of the modal 2", 
    paragraph : "Content of modal 2"
  }
]

function getHeader(header) {
  return '<h5 class="modalheader">'+ header + '</h5>';
}

function createLinkforModal(paragraph, header) {
  return '<div class="readmore"><a href="#modal" data-target="#paragraph" class="openModal" id="openModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" '+paragraph+' " data-header="'+header+'">Read more &raquo;</a></div>'; 
}

for (var i = 0; i < tableEntries.length; i++) {
  var header = tableEntries[i].header
  var paragraph = tableEntries[i].paragraph
  console.log(getHeader(header))
  console.log(createLinkforModal(paragraph, header))
  document.querySelector('#tableEntries').innerHTML += createLinkforModal(paragraph, header)
}
```

```html
<div id="tableEntries"></div>
```

Comment: In the modal the header is still undefined. The console log looks right!

Comment: @StuffToLearn I don't know what you mean with "In the modal the header is still undefined"

Comment: I mean inside the function createLinkforModal() the header is still undefined, so it shows undefined in the modal.

Comment: but it creates `data-header="Title of the modal"`and `data-header="Title of the modal 2"` so it can't be `undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, in the console I see it just right, but in the HTML it says the data-header is undefined.

Comment: @StuffToLearn I add now an HTML output. Can you check it again?

Comment: That works! Let me fiddle with it a bit if I could get it to work like this or inside the function

Comment: accepted this answer! This got me in the right direction with the output, and I was able to use .append() in the end to print out my header and paragraph for the modals content.

Answer (score 0):

if you call like below, `header` will be `undefined` because you have not pass second parameter

```
createLinkforModal(tableEntries[1].paragraph);
```

it should be

```
createLinkforModal(tableEntries[1].paragraph, tableEntries[1].header);
```

then you call `console.log(JSON.parse(header));` and get error this is because `header` is not variable, its function parameter or private variable that accesible only in your function

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach :**

```js
var tableEntries = [
      {
          category : "learning",
          start : 8,
          end : 9,
          duration: 1,
          header : "Title of the modal", 
          paragraph : "Content of modal"
      },{
          category : "learning",
          start : 10,
          end : 11,
          duration: 1,
          header : "Title of the modal 2", 
          paragraph : "Content of modal 2"
      }];
      
for (var i in tableEntries) {
 var res = createLinkforModal(tableEntries[i].paragraph, tableEntries[i].header);
  console.log(res);
}

function createLinkforModal(paragraph, header) {
      return '<div class="readmore"><a href="#modal" data-target="#paragraph" class="openModal" id="openModal" data-toggle="modal" data-id=" '+paragraph+' " data-header="'+header+'">Read more &raquo;</a></div>'; 
};
```

**Result :**
[image]